# SAP - Employee Self-Service API REST

Tags: rest, abap, sap-erp

I use "**Employee Self-Service**" for recording hours in SAP.
Is there a way to interact with the ESS portal using rest api ? in order to create custom scripts for entering hours in the "**Record Working Time**" section?

Thank you

Comment: is there any way to interact with sap through rest calls ?

Comment: these are two different questions and the second one is too vague to be posted here, though it was and [already has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13952900/911419)